# Ruby on Rails: Trying to Get JSON data from API and save to Postgres database - rake aborted! TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql, api

I'm using Ruby on Rails and trying to Get JSON data from a public API and save to a Postgres database.

When I run rake db:seed, I'm getting the following error:

```
rake aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
/db/seeds.rb:21:in `[]'
/db/seeds.rb:21:in `properties'
/db/seeds.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

For reference, line 21 is:

```
json["data"].map do |property|
```

Line 48 is where the method is called:

```
properties
```

Here's the first item in the JSON array to give you an idea of what I'm trying to map from.

```
[
  {
    "PublicationDate": "26/10/2018",
    "PropertyNumber": 2195606,
    "County": "LAOIS",
    "LocalAuthority": "LAOIS COUNTY COUNCIL",
    "Valuation": 70600.0,
    "Category": "RETAIL (SHOPS)",
    "Uses": "SUPERMARKET 2 [500-2500 SQ. M.], -",
    "Address1": "36-42A/1 POUND STREET",
    "Address2": "RATHDOWNEY",
    "Address3": "CO. LAOIS",
    "Address4": "",
    "Address5": "",
    "CarPark": 0,
    "Xitm": 628016.65,
    "Yitm": 678231.8,
    "ValuationReport": [
      {
        "Level": "0      ",
        "FloorUse": "SUPERMARKET",
        "Area": 964.62,
        "NavPerM2": 60.0000,
        "Nav": 57877.200000
      },
      {
        "Level": "0",
        "FloorUse": "OFF LICENCE",
        "Area": 1.00,
        "NavPerM2": 8681.5800,
        "Nav": 8681.580000
      },
      {
        "Level": "0",
        "FloorUse": "FIT-OUT ALLOWANCE",
        "Area": 1.00,
        "NavPerM2": 4051.4000,
        "Nav": 4051.400000
      }
    ]
  },
```

My database schema follows the JSON structure but not exactly (I'm not sure if this is causing an issue):

```
create_table "properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.string "publication_date"
    t.string "property_number"
    t.string "county"
    t.string "local_authority"
    t.string "valuation"
    t.string "category"
    t.string "uses"
    t.string "address_1"
    t.string "address_2"
    t.string "address_3"
    t.string "address_4"
    t.string "address_5"
    t.string "car_park"
    t.string "xitm"
    t.string "yitm"
    t.string "valuation_report"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_properties_on_user_id"
  end
```

Here's my seeds.rb file:

```
require 'rest-client'

# Define Method
def properties

    response = RestClient.get('https://api.valoff.ie/api/Property/GetProperties?Fields=*&LocalAuthority=LAOIS%20COUNTY%20COUNCIL&CategorySelected=RETAIL%20(SHOPS)&Format=csv&Download=false')

    json = JSON.parse response
    
    if !json.nil?
        json["data"].map do |property|
            Property.create(
                publication_date: "#{PublicationDate}",
                property_number: "#{PropertyNumber}",
                county: "#{County}",
                local_authority: "#{LocalAuthority}",
                valuation: "#{Valuation}",
                category: "#{Category}",
                uses: "#{Uses}",
                address_1: "#{Address1}",
                address_2: "#{Address2}",
                address_3: "#{Address3}",
                address_4: "#{Address4}",
                address_5: "#{Address5}",
                car_park: "#{CarPark}",
                xitm: "#{Xitm}",
                yitm: "#{Yitm}",
                valuation_report: "#{ValuationReport}"
            )
        end
    else
        puts "Error seeding properties."
    end

end

# Call Method
properties
```

When I run rake db:seed, I'm getting the following error:

```
rake aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
/db/seeds.rb:21:in `[]'
/db/seeds.rb:21:in `properties'
/db/seeds.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

For reference, line 21 is:

```
json["data"].map do |property|
```

Line 48 is where the method is called:

```
properties
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Which line is line 21 in seeds.rb?

Comment: Hi Tom, line 21 is: json["data"].map do |property|

Comment: Is there a `"data"` field in the JSON? And then, don't you mean `publication_date: property['PublicationDate']` instead of `publication_date: "#{PublicationDate}"`? You're looking for things inside `property` rather than global constants and you don't need all that string interpolation.

Comment: I tried that format as you suggested but I'm getting the same error unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Try a `puts json` to check that the response is what you expect.

Comment: I've done as you suggested by inserting 'puts json' on the line just after 'json = JSON.parse response' and it provides the correct JSON information that I'm looking for so that's good but I'm still getting the error after that.

Comment: You have two issues. First, the parsed JSON response is an `Array`. So, `json["data"]` makes no sense, since arrays are indexed by integer (hence the conversion error). Second, as @mu points out, there is no 'data' attribute on the individual JSON blobs. You likely can just iterate over the array with something like `json.each do |record|` and access the properties directly with `record['PublicationDate']` etc.

Comment: Thanks @rmlockerd, I've done that. Now I'm getting the error: 'rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 16, expected 0..1)
/db/seeds.rb:25:in `block in properties'
/db/seeds.rb:24:in `each'
/db/seeds.rb:24:in `properties'
/db/seeds.rb:142:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the recommendations in the various comments, `json` is an `Array` after the JSON is parsed. Array indexes are integers, so `json["data"]` results in a `TypeError`. Second, there is no `data` field for the JSON records returned. You can simply iterate over the result array and create your records like so:

```ruby
def properties
  response = RestClient.get('https://api.valoff.ie/api/Property/GetProperties?Fields=*&LocalAuthority=LAOIS%20COUNTY%20COUNCIL&CategorySelected=RETAIL%20(SHOPS)&Format=csv&Download=false')

  json = JSON.parse(response)

  json.each do |property|
    puts "Creating property #{property['PropertyNumber']}"
    Property.create!(
      publication_date: property['PublicationDate'],
      property_number: property['PropertyNumber'],
      county: property['County'],
      local_authority: property['LocalAuthority'],
      valuation_report: property['ValuationReport']
      # ... remaining fields omitted for brevity
    )
  end
end
```

You don't need really need the `.nil?` check in your original, since `RestClient` raises an error for any HTTP response codes other than 200-2007. Likewise, `JSON.parse` will raise an error if the response isn't valid JSON.

Result:

```
$ rails db:seed
Creating property 1555903
Creating property 1556133
Creating property 1556998
Creating property 1556516
Creating property 1557007
...
```

Comment: It works thanks! Just one more question: how can I access the array within the ValuationReport property of the JSON object to display the Level, Floor Use etc. separately. Should I be extracting these items and saving them separately when seeding from the API to the database? or is the ValuationReport string in the database parsable in the html.erb? At the moment it displays on the front end as: Valuation Report: [{"Level"=>"1", "FloorUse"=>"OFFICE(S)", "Area"=>23.89, "NavPerM2"=>70.0, "Nav"=>1672.3}, {"Level"=>"0", "FloorUse"=>"OFFICE(S)", "Area"=>74.57, "NavPerM2"=>100.0, "Nav"=>7457.0}]

Comment: I found another similar question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574838/ruby-getting-deeply-nested-json-api-data?rq=1 which suggests a tool called JSONPath which should help to access and store the nested objects/attributes in my database. I'll post the code here when I've fully figured out a working solution. Here's the link to JSONPath: https://github.com/joshbuddy/jsonpath