# Ruby on Rails: How can I use JSONPath to access (and save to database) nested objects/properties within a JSON array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql, jsonpath

I am trying to seed data to my database from a JSON array of objects. I have two separate database tables - Property and Unit (a Property has many Units). I have been able to do this for the property information (property model) successfully with the API requesting the JSON data and then seeding this to the database however the ValuationReport attribute is showing on my front end as a JSON object in string form.

Here is a sample of the JSON data I am working with (I've limited this sample to an array of 3 objects for demonstration purposes):

```
[
  {
    "PublicationDate": "17/09/2019",
    "PropertyNumber": 2198231,
    "County": "CAVAN",
    "LocalAuthority": "CAVAN COUNTY COUNCIL",
    "Valuation": 15090,
    "Category": "OFFICE",
    "Uses": "OFFICE (OVER THE SHOP), -",
    "Address1": "77(1ST & 2ND FL) MAIN STREET",
    "Address2": "CAVAN",
    "Address3": "CO. CAVAN",
    "Address4": "",
    "Address5": "",
    "CarPark": 0,
    "Xitm": 641927.73,
    "Yitm": 804638.3,
    "ValuationReport": [
      {
        "Level": "1",
        "FloorUse": "RESTAURANT",
        "Area": 112.25,
        "NavPerM2": 80,
        "Nav": 8980
      },
      {
        "Level": "2",
        "FloorUse": "RESTAURANT",
        "Area": 98.57,
        "NavPerM2": 62,
        "Nav": 6111.34
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "PublicationDate": "17/09/2019",
    "PropertyNumber": 1558322,
    "County": "CAVAN",
    "LocalAuthority": "CAVAN COUNTY COUNCIL",
    "Valuation": 10200,
    "Category": "OFFICE",
    "Uses": "OFFICE (OWN DOOR), -",
    "Address1": "23E MAIN STREET",
    "Address2": "CAVAN",
    "Address3": "CO. CAVAN",
    "Address4": "",
    "Address5": "",
    "CarPark": 0,
    "Xitm": 641941.19,
    "Yitm": 804875.56,
    "ValuationReport": [
      {
        "Level": "0",
        "FloorUse": "OFFICE(S)",
        "Area": 127.55,
        "NavPerM2": 80,
        "Nav": 10204
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "PublicationDate": "17/09/2019",
    "PropertyNumber": 2116802,
    "County": "CAVAN",
    "LocalAuthority": "CAVAN COUNTY COUNCIL",
    "Valuation": 15140,
    "Category": "OFFICE",
    "Uses": "OFFICE (OWN DOOR), HERITAGE / INTERPRETATIVE CENTRE",
    "Address1": "LOCAL NO/MAP REF: 7AB",
    "Address2": "MULLAGH",
    "Address3": "BAILIEBORO CO. CAVAN",
    "Address4": "",
    "Address5": "",
    "CarPark": 0,
    "Xitm": 668656.19,
    "Yitm": 785281.05,
    "ValuationReport": [
      {
        "Level": "0",
        "FloorUse": "OFFICE(S)",
        "Area": 252.49,
        "NavPerM2": 60,
        "Nav": 15149.4
property_id: unit[property.id]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The difficulty I am having is with the ValuationReport attribute which is an array of varying size for each element in the JSON array of properties. So some properties will have a ValuationReport array containing only one object whereas other properties will contain a ValuationReport object with several objects. I would like to save each of these nested objects from each ValuationReport array to a separate unit in my database (unit model).

I have used the JSONPath Gem to try to access the required elements but there is something I am doing wrong.

When I run '$ rails db:seed', it is now running until a point and I am receiving the following errors:

```
Creating property 2198231
Creating unit.
rails aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
/db/seeds.rb:62:in `[]'
/db/seeds.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in properties'
/db/seeds.rb:58:in `each'
/db/seeds.rb:58:in `block in properties'
/db/seeds.rb:36:in `each'
/db/seeds.rb:36:in `properties'
/db/seeds.rb:207:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here are the relevant Gems from my Gemfile:

```
# REST Client for APIs
gem 'rest-client', '~> 2.1'

# JSONPath - for acessing values in nested JSON objects.
gem 'jsonpath', '~> 0.5.8'
```

My database schema is below:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_11_07_130018) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "publication_date"
    t.string "property_number"
    t.string "county"
    t.string "local_authority"
    t.decimal "valuation"
    t.string "category"
    t.string "uses"
    t.string "address_1"
    t.string "address_2"
    t.string "address_3"
    t.string "address_4"
    t.string "address_5"
    t.decimal "car_park"
    t.decimal "xitm"
    t.decimal "yitm"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "units", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "level"
    t.string "floor_use"
    t.decimal "area"
    t.decimal "nav_per_m2"
    t.decimal "nav"
    t.bigint "property_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["property_id"], name: "index_units_on_property_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "units", "properties"
end
```

My seeds.rb file is below. I have tried to use an index (i) to ensure that the loop for the ValuationReport array of objects is looping once for each property and creating all of the units that exist within each property.

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'
require 'jsonpath'

# Define Method - API Request
def properties

    response = RestClient.get('https://api.valoff.ie/api/Property/GetProperties?Fields=*&LocalAuthority=CAVAN%20COUNTY%20COUNCIL&CategorySelected=OFFICE&Format=csv&Download=false')
    json = JSON.parse(response)

    json.each do |property|
        puts "Creating property #{property['PropertyNumber']}"

        Property.create!(

            publication_date: property['PublicationDate'],
            property_number: property['PropertyNumber'],
            county: property['County'],
            local_authority: property['LocalAuthority'],
            valuation: property['Valuation'],
            category: property['Category'],
            uses: property['Uses'],
            address_1: property['Address1'],
            address_2: property['Address2'],
            address_3: property['Address3'],
            address_4: property['Address4'],
            address_5: property['Address5'],
            car_park: property['CarPark'],
            xitm: property['Xitm'],
            yitm: property['Yitm'],
            units: 
                JsonPath.new('$.ValuationReport').on(property).each do |unit|
                    puts "Creating unit."
                    Unit.create!(
                        level: unit['$.Level'],
                        floor_use: unit['$.FloorUse'],
                        area: unit['$.Area'],
                        nav_per_m2: unit['$.NavPerM2'],
                        nav: unit['$.Nav'],
                        property_id: unit['property.id']
                    )
                end
        )
    end
end

# Call Method
properties
```

Appreciate your time and help!

Comment: If I understand this correctly when you are within a property you are only dealing with the JSON of one property, hence the path of all 'units' is simply `$.ValuationReport`; no indexer needed. BTW: The propery_id is not set during unit creation.

Comment: Thanks wp78de, I've updated the path, removed the index and included the property_id however I'm still receiving errors - I have updated these above also.

Comment: I've updated the seeds.rb file to include JsonPath syntax to wrap around path - JsonPath.new('$.ValuationReport').on(property).each do |unit| . Also included apostrophes around the JSON attributes to be mapped to the database. At least now it is running to a point. Errors also updated.

Comment: Hm, is the `$` root needed within the unit fields, or should it just read: `level: unit['Level'],` ...

Comment: Tried it without the $ root within the unit fields but still getting the exact same errors.

Comment: I am sorry, I wish I could help better but I do not have a Ruby environment right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario you do not need JsonPath. I updated your script:

- removed JsonPath in favour of using `property['ValuationReport']`
- removed `$.` from json keys
- first you should create a Property and then use its ID in Units (alternatively you can setup `accepts_nested_attributes` in models)

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'
require 'jsonpath'

# Define Method - API Request
def properties

    response = RestClient.get('https://api.valoff.ie/api/Property/GetProperties?Fields=*&LocalAuthority=CAVAN%20COUNTY%20COUNCIL&CategorySelected=OFFICE&Format=csv&Download=false')
    json = JSON.parse(response)

    json.each do |property|
        puts "Creating property #{property['PropertyNumber']}"

        property_model = Property.create!(

            publication_date: property['PublicationDate'],
            property_number: property['PropertyNumber'],
            county: property['County'],
            local_authority: property['LocalAuthority'],
            valuation: property['Valuation'],
            category: property['Category'],
            uses: property['Uses'],
            address_1: property['Address1'],
            address_2: property['Address2'],
            address_3: property['Address3'],
            address_4: property['Address4'],
            address_5: property['Address5'],
            car_park: property['CarPark'],
            xitm: property['Xitm'],
            yitm: property['Yitm']
        )


        property['ValuationReport'].each do |unit|
          puts "Creating unit."
          property_model.units.create!(
            level: unit['Level'],
            floor_use: unit['FloorUse'],
            area: unit['Area'],
            nav_per_m2: unit['NavPerM2'],
            nav: unit['Nav']
          )
        end
    end
end

# Call Method
properties
```

Comment: Thank you DonPaulie, I have another thing I want to add to this. I have a method to convert Xitm (lat) and Yitm (long) to GPS. Would you know how I could pass these in as parameters to a new attribute? My suggestiont is this - gps: property[convert_ITM_To_GPS(property['Xitm'], property['Yitm'])]

Comment: There are a few problems. First of all, you should ask a question as another question. I see lack of your understanding of imperative programming. Try saving every ITM coordinate to a variable. then pass both of them to the method and save the result to another variable.

Comment: I figured it out. I used the method to do the conversion before the .create block. I then set lat and long variables from the two values that the method returned. Finally, I used these variables in the .create block to assign the values to two attributes, gps_lat and gps_long .